# Ordenar por Data no firebase em java

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de dados no firebase que organize por data... tentando `orderBy("datePosted")` mas não me mostra nada.

```
CollectionReference referenceFellow = db.collection("Fellow");
Query query = referenceFellow.whereEqualTo("fellowUserName", currentUser);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
            if ((Boolean) documentSnapshot.getData().get("fellowAtive")) {
                CollectionReference referenceCommunity = db.collection("Notifications");
                Query query = referenceCommunity.whereEqualTo("communityName", documentSnapshot.getData().get("fellowCommunity").toString());
                query.orderBy("datePosted").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {

                                Notifications notifications = documentSnapshot.toObject(Notifications.class);
                                notificationsList.add(notifications);
                                recyclerViewAdapterNotifications = new RecyclerViewAdapterNotifications(notificationsList,view.getContext());
                                GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(), 1);

                                rvNotifications.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                                rvNotifications.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterNotifications);
                             }
                           }
                       }
                   });
                }
            }
       }
    }
});
```

Quando eu tiro o orderBy funciona perfeitamente

Comment: O nome da coluna está certo?

Comment: sim meu caro, esta sim

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, você está chamando o método orderBy("datePosted") após o método whereEqualTo("communityName", documentSnapshot.getData().get("fellowCommunity").toString()). No entanto, a ordenação deve ser chamada antes de executar a consulta.

Para ordenar a consulta pela data, você pode modificar o código da seguinte maneira:

```
CollectionReference referenceCommunity = db.collection("Notifications");
Query query = referenceCommunity
        .whereEqualTo("communityName", documentSnapshot.getData().get("fellowCommunity").toString())
        .orderBy("datePosted");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    // Resto do código...
```

Dessa forma, a consulta será ordenada pela data de postagem e, em seguida, você pode iterar sobre os documentos resultantes e adicionar os dados à lista de notificações.

Além disso, o RecyclerViewAdapterNotifications deve ser instanciado fora do loop, caso contrário, será criado um novo adapter a cada iteração do loop. Você pode fazer isso antes do loop for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {:

```
notificationsList.clear(); // Limpar a lista antes de adicioná-los novamente
recyclerViewAdapterNotifications = new RecyclerViewAdapterNotifications(notificationsList, view.getContext());
rvNotifications.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterNotifications);
```

Comment: boa, obrigado pela resposta, vou verificar